# Graphs which are built from complete graphs : Reference request

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-theory, terminology

Let $V$ be a set of $n$ vertices. Fix $3 \le k \le n$. Let $\binom V k$ be the set of all $k$ element subsets of $V$.

We add the edges in $V$ as follows: Let $\mathcal S \subseteq \binom V k$ be fixed. For each $F \in \mathcal S$, I am making the vertices in $F$ mutually adjacent. Let's call this graph $G_k(\mathcal S)$.

1. I want to learn how the graph $G_k(\mathcal S)$ looks like?
2. Is there any name for $G_k(\mathcal S)$ in the literature?
3. Some references regarding these graphs.

Kindly share your thoughts. Thank you.

Comment: This brings to mind the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_complex . In terms of this, every $1$-dimensional face (but not necessarily every $2$-dimensional face) is part of a face of dimension $k-1$. (I admit that does not sound very helpful.)

Comment: This seems a little broad, especially Q1. For example, every graph can arise with $k=2$.

Comment: @verret I want to start from triangles. Even though $k=2$ is everything I believe even $k=3$ this class is something different and well-studied.

Comment: @VilleSalo Sorry. I am not much familiar with the complex. I shall check. Thank you.

Comment: Well, for a given $k$, the class of graph one gets is exactly the graphs such that every edge is contained in a $k$-clique. So for $k=3$, it's graphs such that every edge is in a triangle.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any classification or a name for graphs satisfying this property?

Comment: Especially in computer science / complexity theory, if we were to pick one size-$k$ subset, we would call this "planting a clique" in the graph.

Comment: I think that “graphs with every edge in a triangle” is the simplest description of this family, and that no significant or interesting alternative characterisations are widely known. I’ve considered regular graphs (quartic, more precisely) with this property and did not come across anything in general.

Comment: @GordonRoyle Thanks for your efforts. I will also check from a similar perspective to regular graphs. Thank you again.